# Swift type casting for parameter passing, EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x14)

Tags: ios, swift

In my code, I have a line:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!){
    if segue.identifier == "seguetotable"{
        var tableView: TableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as TableViewController
        var callBack: TableViewCallBack = self
        tableView.delegate = callBack;
        NSLog("segueprepared")
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to use the delegate method to pass parameters. It throws a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x14) error at line:

```
tableView.delegate = callBack;
```

I searched on google and stackoverflow, it seems to be an error related to the memory management. But I cannot figure out why.
The delegate is defined as

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var items: [Thumbnail]=[]
    var delegate: TableViewCallBack? = nil
```

where TableViewCallBack is a protocol defined as

```
protocol TableViewCallBack {
    func updateImage(items: [Thumbnail]);
}
```

The backtrace is as follows:

- thread #1: tid = 0xd6a8a, 0x02004ab8 libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 56, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
  <ul>
  <li>frame #0: 0x02004ab8 libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 56
  frame #1: 0x000914d0 FootprintinWorld`FootprintinWorld.ViewController.prepareForSegue (segue=0x7bf66130, sender=Some, self=0x7bff37b0)(ObjectiveC.UIStoryboardSegue, sender : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>) -> () + 880 at ViewController.swift:53
  frame #2: 0x000917b6 FootprintinWorld`@objc FootprintinWorld.ViewController.prepareForSegue (FootprintinWorld.ViewController)(ObjectiveC.UIStoryboardSegue, sender : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional) -> () + 86 at ViewController.swift:0
  frame #3: 0x010d0b37 UIKit`-[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 199
  frame #4: 0x010d0bc5 UIKit`-[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 116
  frame #5: 0x01c927cd libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
  frame #6: 0x00ab523d UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
  frame #7: 0x00e25840 UIKit`-[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 139
  frame #8: 0x01c927cd libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
  frame #9: 0x00ab523d UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
  frame #10: 0x00ab51cf UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
  frame #11: 0x00be8e86 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 69
  frame #12: 0x00be92a3 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 598
  frame #13: 0x00be850d UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 660
  frame #14: 0x00b0560a UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874
  frame #15: 0x00b060e5 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 791
  frame #16: 0x00acb549 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
  frame #17: 0x00adb37e UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 20690
  frame #18: 0x00aafb19 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2206
  frame #19: 0x001c41df CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
  frame #20: 0x001b9ced CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
  frame #21: 0x001b9248 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 952
  frame #22: 0x001b8bcb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
  frame #23: 0x001b89fb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
  frame #24: 0x0403424f GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
  frame #25: 0x0403408c GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
  frame #26: 0x00ab38b6 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1526
  frame #27: 0x0009a93e FootprintinWorld`top_level_code + 78 at AppDelegate.swift:12
  frame #28: 0x0009a97b FootprintinWorld`main + 43 at AppDelegate.swift:0
  frame #29: 0x023e9ac9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1

***Update:***
The bug has been found. The error is caused by line:

```
var tableView: TableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as TableViewController
```

Though I still do not know why xcode tells me the bad exec happens two lines later...

The reason is I embedded my TableViewController in a Navigation Controller. Hence, the app cannot convert a navigation controller to a TableViewController (i.e., my custom subclass based on UITableViewController). In order to solve the problem, I just unwrap the TableViewController from the navigation controller. It turns out that if the TableViewController is pushed by a segue from a navigation controller, then it will automatically has the area for navigation bar buttons. So no need to have another navigation controller in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as NameOFYourController
}
```

You are casting it wrong, Surely you have a subclass of `UITableViewController` where you want to go. Cast it as that controller. Hope this helps.. :)